# Could I use several frontings in fronting?

Tags: fronting

> The technician it was.

Above mentioned one fronting. Applying another two frontings to this text results in

> Technician the was it.

Is the last sentence correct?

Comment: "The technician it was" is a *very* unusual utterance. Avoid such constructions.

Comment: "Fronting" a sentence element doesn't simply mean that you can put any word at the front. Please indicate what you already know about this issue so that people can give you a good answer; we generally don't proofread sentences here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The technician, it was."  This is a rare construction.  It is vaguely Germanic, and is considered stereotypical of the speech patterns of Yiddish speaking people in the 20th century.  Learners should avoid this unless they have a very specific need.

Fronting doesn't mean "just put anything in front" It follows specific rules.  For example the interrogative is fronted in questions like "What did you eat?"  (As a pronoun, "what" is the object of eat, so normally would follow the verb). There is a specific grammar rule at work here.

You can't "front" the noun in front of a determinative. "Technician the" is incorrect.

Also incorrect "The it was technician".  and  "It technician the was."  Other re-arrangements have different meanings, and usually they form questions "Was it the technician?".

English has syntactic rules. You can't place words in any order.